# What does まわりであーだこーだ mean in this sentence?

Tags: translation, words, meaning, manga

I don't really understand the "まわりであーだこーだ" part in the following sentence I read in a manga:

> こそこそ人のこと調べたり、**まわりであーだこーだ**、女は面倒くさい

Does まわりで means 人のまわりで?

My guess for "あーだこーだ" is that it means "making a fuss", here. Am I getting it right?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Hi, Perhaps you should give us your version of what is being said? In explaining the context you might work out the answer, we would not have second guess it ,and even you still don't get you might get more answers.

Comment: Hi! My understanding is that girls are annoying because they always secretly investigate about people, making a fuss all around them. The one saying that is a very popular boy amongst girls, so he's probably dealing with annoying stalkers or at least girls admiring him every time he goes by.

Comment: I think it means gossiping in this context. あーだ、こうだ literally means "it's like this and like that". The guy in the manga means to say that girls are nosy pains.

Answer (score 2):

**まわりで:** Oh this is ambiguous... I think the speaker wants to say 「**俺の**まわりで (literally, *around me*)」 here, but it can be taken in two opposite ways... "behind my back" or "clinging around me". I guess the former is the likely interpretation here because it is preceded by "こそこそ人のこと調べたり", but I'm not sure.

**ああだこうだと言う:** (((ああ+だ)+(こう+だ))と言う). To say various trivial things. To quibble.

Comment: So "To say various trivial things. To quibble." you mean "to make fuss, or noise about trivial things that are not really of any consequence"?

Comment: "Make a *big* fuss/trouble" is not what I want to say. "noise about trivial things (which is just bothering)" is closer, I think.